# BottomSheetDialogFragment is not showing up

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I've followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc) to implement BottomSheetDiaogFragment in my android application.

this is my bottom sheet layout (bottom_sheet.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/rb1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/rb2" />

</RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

BottomSheetDialogFragment class:

```
class BottomSheetTaskRepeat : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }
}
```

activity:

```
private val bottomSheetTaskRepeat = BottomSheetTaskRepeat()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    bottomSheetTaskRepeat.show(supportFragmentManager, "my_bottom_sheet")
}
```

The problem is that the bottom sheet is not showing up! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint to check if execution is reaching `bottomSheetTaskRepeat.show..`? Because I ran your code and it was working perfecly.

Comment: Its a good idea to check if there are any `dismiss()` calls inside bottomsheet dialog fragment. Also check in the place where it is called. Sometimes sudden dismiss also looks like that.

Answer (score 6):

This is a late Answer, I am writing for anyone who will face the same problem, This is what I found:

For some reasons non-constrained views heights do not work in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. A view whose height is like `wrap_content` will not show.*(But the shadow will be there)*, but when you specify its height like `80dp` it works.

For this question go and change your `RadioGroup` height and specify it like to:

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Hope that is helpful.

UPDATE:
Since the default container of `BottomSheetDailogFragment` is `FrameLayout` and is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, You can override that on your Fragment `onStart` method like this (Kotlin):

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val containerID = com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
    val bottomSheet: FrameLayout? = dialog?.findViewById(containerID)
    bottomSheet?.let {
        BottomSheetBehavior.from<FrameLayout?>(it).state =
            BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
        bottomSheet.layoutParams.height = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    }

    view?.post {
        val params = (view?.parent as View).layoutParams as (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
        val behavior = params.behavior
        val bottomSheetBehavior = behavior as (BottomSheetBehavior)
        bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = view?.measuredHeight ?: 0
        (bottomSheet?.parent as? View)?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

1. Create and use the parameterless static method `newInstance` in your `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and call the `show()` method on it.
2. Try `LinearLayoutCompat` as a root layout instead of `ConstraintLayout`.
3. Try a colourful background to the root layout to get an idea.
4. Try `match_parent` height for the root layout.
5. Make sure that the `dismiss()` or `cancel()` is not being called on it immediately.
6. Check visibility.
7. If it contains a `recyclerView`, make sure that it has items, `getItemCount` is not returning 0, and that we are setting up the values properly!
8. Restart both: PC and Device if your changes are not reflecting because of Android Studio errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **supportFragmentManager** you have to use **childFragmentManager**,if you are inflating from inner fragments.

```
private val bottomSheetTaskRepeat = BottomSheetTaskRepeat()
bottomSheetTaskRepeat.show(childFragmentManager, "my_bottom_sheet")
```